# alternative to authorization filter in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-mvc-filters

I am quite familiar with the `Authorization Filter` in mvc to authorize access to particular url in mvc.

I m working on scenario where i have no control over the `Controller` naming `CustomCtrl` written for some `Action` in my application.

How can i enforce `Authorization` rules in this case.

eg. if some one login in my application with `User` attribute, which i m storing in `session state`, how can i restrict that user to access the url `Admin/CustomCtrl/SomeAction`, Like something we can do in `ASP.NET` application by writting `CustomHandler`

Comment: Have you considered using a global filter?

Comment: Global filter really done the trick for me. thanks a lot @codran